# Fetch a number after a specific text from a json response

Tags: python, json, regex

With Python, I am trying to extract the number 1631 from a string corresponding to the field value of the keyword `numHits`. The keyword is fixed. How can I use a regex for it?

```
{'statusCode': 200,
 'numHits': 1631,
 'hits': [{'lastSeen': '2019-09-25',
   'imageHeight': 360,
```

Comment: There is no need to use regex. If it's json you can parse it like a dictionary. i.e. `your_data['numHits']`

Comment: why use regex? Its a dictionary, so you can just call it : dictionary[key]

Comment: To complement @KostasCharitidis, to parse json in dict, import json and d = json.loads(html_response)

Comment: @Wonka actually if the page returns `json` the response itself has a `response.json()` function

Comment: What we see here is not a valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

A complete example would be:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('your_url')
your_data = response.json()
print(your_data['numHits'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex for it anyway, here is one for positive number values only:

```py
import re

json_str = "{'statusCode': 200, 'numHits': 1631, 'hits': [{'lastSeen': '2019-09-25', 'imageHeight': 360,..."

r = re.compile(r"'numHits':\s+(\d+)")

res = r.search(json_str) # <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(20, 35), match="'numHits': 1631">
res.group(1) # '1631'


# be careful with non maching strings
res = r.search("asd") # None
res.group(1) # -> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the JSON in your question is a wrong copy / paste and the real data is a valid JSON...

If what you show in your answer is a simple dictionary use:

```
print(json_data['numHits'])
```

In case this is a string coming from a http response you can use:

```
json_data = response.json()  
print(json_data['numHits'])
```

In case it is a string not coming from a http response please use:

```
import json  
json_data = json.loads(variable_containing_data)  
print(json_data['numHits'])
```

Comment: Just indent your code part correctly. Also no need to parse the response data with `json` it already has a `.json()` function to do so

Comment: From mobile phone indenting / putting code is a mess. Trying now to clean a bit...

Comment: Hi @Mayank!
If my answer was useful please remember to upvote and / or choose it as final answer.

Thanks!